# MS Access SQL query on setting variables?

Tags: sql, ms-access

HI Is it possible to store a variable to allow me to use the dates from a previous prompt? For example if i prompt a user for 2 dates like this: -

```
WHERE LatestGamma.ConfirmedPortingDate Between [Please Provide 1st Date (dd/mm/yyyy)] And [Please Provide 2nd Date (dd/mm/yyyy)];
```

and then i want to use the same dates from the prompted ConfirmedPorting dates like this: -  `AND LatestGamma.ProposedPortingDate Between [VariableName1stDateFromPrompt] And [VariableName2ndDateFromPrompt];`

Can this be done with access?

Here is my modified code after speaking with Gord and still does not work as expected, its errors if i leave the parameters in and runs if i take them out, but the results pull in records that dont meet the criteria IE Confirmed and proposed date are both different from the prompted ones:

```
   PARAMETERS 
    [Please Provide 1st Date (dd/mm/yyyy)] DateTime, 
    [Please Provide 2nd Date (dd/mm/yyyy)] DateTime;
SELECT LatestGamma.OrderId, LatestGamma.MainNumber, LatestGamma.LineType, LatestGamma.Company, LatestGamma.CPStatus, LatestGamma.ConfirmedPortingDate, LatestGamma.ProposedPortingDate, LatestGamma.RequestedDate
FROM LatestGamma
WHERE LatestGamma.ConfirmedPortingDate Between [Please Provide 1st Date (dd/mm/yyyy)] And [Please Provide 2nd Date (dd/mm/yyyy)]
OR LatestGamma.ProposedPortingDate Between [Please Provide 1st Date (dd/mm/yyyy)] And [Please Provide 2nd Date (dd/mm/yyyy)]
ORDER BY LatestGamma.Company;
```

Comment: *"errors if i leave the parameters in"*  What is the error message?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you input the parameter values in *yyyy-mm-dd* or *mm/dd/yyyy* format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can just use the same parameter name repeatedly and the user will only be prompted once for each parameter. For clarity, you may want to add a PARAMETERS prefix to your query, like this

```sql
PARAMETERS 
    [Please Provide 1st Date (yyyy/mm/dd)] DateTime, 
    [Please Provide 2nd Date (yyyy/mm/dd)] DateTime;
SELECT stuff FROM wherever
WHERE LatestGamma.ConfirmedPortingDate Between [Please Provide 1st Date (yyyy/mm/dd)] And [Please Provide 2nd Date (yyyy/mm/dd)]
    AND LatestGamma.ProposedPortingDate Between [Please Provide 1st Date (yyyy/mm/dd)] And [Please Provide 2nd Date (yyyy/mm/dd)];
```

Comment: Thank you, but would that not ask me twice for each date? I am trying to avaid this by the user being asked onces for each dates then the following proposed date accepts what was input on the ConfirmedPortingDate prompts without reprompting...

Comment: @MoiD101 No, as I said, if you use the *exact same parameter name* in more than one place then Access will only prompt for that parameter value once.

Comment: Ok so something is not working correct here Gord, if i leave in the parameters bit, i get error stating the its to complex, if i take out the parameters it runs but pulls out reocrds that dont have either of the specified confirmed or proposed date aswell as records that do ill post my modified code above

Comment: @MoiD101 re: date formats - My apologies, I should have noticed this sooner: Prompting for date parameters as `dd/mm/yyyy` is problematic for Access because the Access Database Engine **always** interprets ambiguous `xx/yy/zzzz` dates as `mm/dd/yyyy` regardless of the Regional Settings in the Windows Control Panel. In other words, `04/02/2013` will always be interpreted as April 2, not February 4. You should prompt for dates as `yyyy/mm/dd` if you want to continue with this approach.

Comment: @MoiD101 re: "too complex" - I just copied and pasted the query from your updated question into Access 2010 and it did not complain that anything was "too complex". Question: Is [LatestGamma] a saved query? (When I tested it here I just created a local table named [LatestGamma] so that might account for the difference.)

Comment: no the latestGamma is a linked table to and excel spreadsheet which is a twice daily report that come from an external source

Comment: ok its looking a whole lot better although i now need to do some comparisons on the data output, anyway ill check it thoroughly tomorrow (its getting late for working here in the uk so ill give it a res for tonight) thank you Gord (Goddamn Microsoft) :)